# Discord.py - Opening a hyperlink in discord client

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I'm trying to open a hyperlink to a channel that the bot sends in the discord client, but instead it just opens the link in a new window, if the bot just sends the normal link (without it being hyperlinked) then it'll work fine

```py
@client.command()
async def fullv(ctx):

 guild=ctx.message.guild
 author=ctx.message.author
 if ctx.author.voice and ctx.author.voice.channel:
    channel = ctx.author.voice.channel
 else:
    await ctx.send("You are not connected to a voice channel")
    return
 vc=f"https://discordapp.com/channels/{guild.id}/{channel.id}"

 embed=discord.Embed(title="Join Full Voice", url=vc, description="Full voice is a DM voice chat in a Discord Server!", color=0x00ff40)

 await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

It's supposed to send a hyperlink with a full voice chat (a DM voice in a server) but instead it opens discord in a new window

Comment: It's not possible. Anyway just mentioning the channel will have the same effect aka `#text-for-voice` It won't work from other guilds as link but it really shouldn't in the first place (links work only if the user is in linked guild so why not just send channel mention)

Comment: It's a voice channel, so I can't mention it. When you join a voice channel if you type: ```https://discordapp.com/channels/serverid/voicechannelid``` once you click it it'll make it look like you're in a DM Voice Chat when your'e in a Discord Server Voice Chat (I can't explain things well, so here's a link to what I mean, I do not own the video or took any part in it!) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k771oVxPOi0

Comment: I see, neat trick. Embed urls will alway open in a new tab so I guess this trick is possible only by using regular url text.

Comment: ah ok, I hoped that's work, thanks anyway!